# What type of java code is this?

Tags: java, c#

```
public class ParametricIndicators {
    static Method GET_PARAMETRIC_INDICATOR; //equal to a double number (as parameter)

    static {
        try {

            GET_PARAMETRIC_INDICATOR = ParametricIndicators.class.
            getDeclaredMethod("getParametricIndicator", new Class[]{ArrayList.class, short.class});

        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Predicate.static: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

I am new to Java, and I am converting a java codebase to C#. I want to know what type of code is this? Is it a getter?

```
 static {
            try {

                GET_PARAMETRIC_INDICATOR = ParametricIndicators.class.
                getDeclaredMethod("getParametricIndicator", new Class[]{ArrayList.class, short.class});

            } 
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Predicate.static: " + e);
            }
        }
```

Comment: It's called a [static initialization block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html).

Comment: This is a static block. I guess it is the same in C#.

Comment: In C#, this would be a static constructor.